# How to debug error of "unknown type name __progmem__"?

Tags: atmega, programming

I'm using atmel studio 6.1 with a code containing   
but on compilation conpiler gives error as mentioned above and after googling error,I found that this variable **progmem** has been depriciated,but no solution for fixing it.
so anyone can plz help me?
I'm writing this code for ATmega32 to control GLCD JHD12864E.
excerpt of code

```
#ifndef _FONT_H_
#define _FONT_H_
#define __PROG_TYPES_COMPAT__
#include "avr/pgmspace.h"
#include "types.h"

//Constants
#define FONT_OFFSET_WIDTH 2
#define FONT_OFFSET_HEIGHT 3
#define FONT_OFFSET_FIRSTCHAR 4
#define FONT_OFFSET_CHARCOUNT 5
#define FONT_OFFSET_WTABLE 6

//Main Selected Font
const __progmem__ *font;

//Functions
void __GFXInitFont();

UINT8 GFXGetFontHeight();

UINT8 __GFXReadFontData(UINT16 add);

UINT8 __GFXReadPGM(const __progmem__ *ptr);

void GFXSetFont(const __progmem__ *new_font);

#endif
```

Comment: Since the type specifier/qualifier is deprecated, and your toolchain doesn't understand it, have you tried ... removing it?  This code would be more portable if it defined a macro called PROGMEM which conditionally expands to nothing or to `__progmem__`.  Perhaps there is a header file which defines `__progmem__`.

Comment: Did you have a link to the LCD library you can post? As Kaz said you can probably remove it but in this case you'll need to add a datatype as well, possibly something like `void` or `uint8_t` would do depending on how the library is written.

Comment: Yes, there *is* a header file for that: [`<avr/pgmspace.h>`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html). It looks like `PGM_P` is the data type you are looking for.

Comment: @PeterJ Progfx provides this library for GLCD whose font.h lib contains this variable type Link for same is http://progfx.org/download